# How to find first integral of a system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system $x'=y, y'=-1-x+x^2+y^2$. I know that $x^2+y^2-1=0$ is an invariant curve of the system but how do i find a first integral of the system?

Answer (score 1):

Write
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{y'}{x'} = \frac{-1-x+x^2+y^2}{y} = \frac{x^2-x-1}{y}+y
,
$$
or equivalently
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} - y = \frac{x^2-x-1}{y}
.
$$
This looks promising, since we see something beginning to look like separation of variables. Multiplying by the integrating factor $e^{-x}$ gives
$$
\frac{d}{dx} \bigl( e^{-x} y \bigr) = \frac{e^{-x} (x^2-x-1)}{y}
,
$$
or, in terms of the new dependent variable $z(x) = e^{-x} y(x)$,
$$
\frac{dz}{dx} = \frac{e^{-2x} (x^2-x-1)}{z}
.
$$
Now the variables $x$ and $z$ are indeed separated, and we can proceed as usual:
$$
\int z \, dz = \int e^{-2x} (x^2-x-1) \, dx
,
$$
hence
$$
\tfrac12 z^2 = 
\tfrac12 e^{-2x} (1-x^2) + C
.
$$
This means that $C = \tfrac12 (e^{-x} y)^2 - \tfrac12 e^{-2x} (1-x^2)$ is a first integral, or maybe $D=2C$ is nicer:
$$
D(x,y) = e^{-2x} (x^2+y^2-1)
.
$$